# How do I use pivot_longer to go from this dataframe to another? (plus dtype issue)

Tags: r, tidyr

I cannot work out how to get df1 pivot into df2:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  id = c("id_1", "id_2", "id_3"),
  item1.aspect.1 = c("a", "b", "c"),
  item1.aspect.2 = c(1,2,3),
  item1.aspect.3 = c("[12,34]", "[56,78]", "[99,10]"),
  item2.aspect.1 = c("a", "b", "c"),
  item2.aspect.2 = c(1,2,3),
  item2.aspect.3 = c("[12,34]", "[56,78]", "[99,10]"),
  item3.aspect.1 = c("a", "b", "c"),
  item3.aspect.2 = c(1,2,3),
  item3.aspect.3 = c("[12,34]", "[56,78]", "[99,10]")
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  id = c("id_1", "id_2", "id_3"),
  aspect.1 = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"),
  aspect.2 = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
  aspect.3 = c("[12,34]", "[56,78]", "[99,10]", "[12,34]", "[56,78]", "[99,10]", "[12,34]", "[56,78]", "[99,10]")
)
```

I assume I use pivot_longer, and was trying to achieve the results like this:

```
df2 <- pivot_longer(df1, c("item1.aspect.1", "item1.aspect.2", "item1.aspect.3",
                           "item2.aspect.1", "item2.aspect.2", "item2.aspect.3",
                           "item3.aspect.1", "item3.aspect.2", "item3.aspect.3"))
```

I think the pivot command is correct, but I get this error to do with types:

> Can't combine `item1.aspect.1` (character) and `item1.aspect.2` (double)

I know I need to specify something using the `values_ptypes`, but I don't really understand what is best to do in this case and how to write it. I guess everything as a character would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it has nothing to do with `values_ptypes`. You need to set `.value` into `names_to`.

From `?pivot_longer`:

> `.value` indicates that component of the name defines the name of the column containing the cell values, overriding `values_to`.

```
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("item"),
               names_to = c("item", ".value"),
               names_pattern = "(.+?)\\.(.+)")

# A tibble: 9 x 5
  id    item  aspect.1 aspect.2 aspect.3
  <chr> <chr> <chr>       <dbl> <chr>   
1 id_1  item1 a               1 [12,34] 
2 id_1  item2 a               1 [12,34] 
3 id_1  item3 a               1 [12,34] 
4 id_2  item1 b               2 [56,78] 
5 id_2  item2 b               2 [56,78] 
6 id_2  item3 b               2 [56,78] 
7 id_3  item1 c               3 [99,10] 
8 id_3  item2 c               3 [99,10] 
9 id_3  item3 c               3 [99,10]
```

---

`names_pattern` breaks up column names into 3 parts:

```
                  (.+?)    \\.      (.+)
item1.aspect.1 = 'item1' + '.' + 'aspect.1'
```

Comment: Amazing. Although, I (trying to make the problem as minimal as possible) didn't include the fact that I have some other columns which should just remain wide (and so would be pasted multiple times long ways). How do I preserve these? Using the command you gave me, some get deleted, others remain but are mainly filed with NAs.

Comment: @syntheso you can use the `cols` argument to select which columns you want to pivot into longer format. Check my edit. You can try different `<tidy-select>` functions to choose columns you want to pivot.

Comment: Thanks, I don't see how your edit relates to the cols argument though?

Comment: @syntheso I revise `-id` to `starts_with("item")`. They control the `cols` argument.

Comment: In my full problem, I get this error: Error: no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"
I don't really understand it/can't figure it out. I am not even using select_. I am using select as in your example.

Comment: @syntheso The problem may result from how you set the `cols` argument. It depends on  the column names of your full data. Could you provide all column names to me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218911/discussion-between-syntheso-and-darren-tsai).